# How to stop Blender from rounding numbers?

Tags: scale

So I need to have objects that are as small as 0.03125m and move them at 0.015625m invervals. Whenever I try to work with this values Blender rounds them.

**Is there a way to increase it's precision? If not, is there a workaround for this?**

I tried to have my scene unit scale set to .001m and lenght to millimeters, but the rounding still happens.

- Having everything in meters will round .03125m to .0313m
- Having
  everything in millimeters will round 31.25mm to 31.3mm

I thought on just making everything bigger and scale it down on export once it's done. Will precision be lost in this case? I'm watching this post, if you feel some info is missing please point out and I will edit the post instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I guess blender doesn't round these values?

I changed my scene units to display separated units (e.g. 1m 0cm).
And BAM, edge lenght is displaying the correct (original) values.
Also I noticed that when creating a mesh the transform values will be rounded, but
item transform shows the correct values.

**Blender was not rounding the values themselves. It was just displaying them rounded.**

This is absurdly counterintuitive and really should never happen.
If anyone stumbles across this I hope this helps.